# Подскажите способ решения поставленной задачи

Tags: unity3d

Начинаю изучать Unity. В программе создал Cube_1 и масштабировал по X и Z. Это будет "поверхность". Создал второй Cube_2. И переместил его выше "поверхности". Чтобы он как-бы лежал на "поверхности". Задача программы: заставить Cube_2 перекатываться по "поверхности" слева направо со скоростью 1 градус поворота за кадр. Т.е. сначала Cube_2 лежит горизонтально. В следующем кадре Cube_2 поворачивается на 1 градус по часовой стрелке вокруг своего центра. В результате этого Cube_2 опирается теперь на свой правый нижний угол и приподнимается над "поверхностью". Так продолжается пока Cube_2 поворачивается на 90 градусов. И теперь он стоит на своём угле точно вертикально. После этого Cube_2 опираясь на тот же угол начинает опускаться на свою следующую сторону пока не ляжет полностью на "поверхность". И алгоритм начинается сначала.
Я могу заставить Cube_2 вращаться с помощью скрипта. Но при этом его положение должно вычисляться с помощью самого Unity. Не могу понять как и с помощью чего решить этот вопрос?
Подскажите, какие компоненты (и какие параметры этих компонентов использовать) для решения поставленной задачи?

Comment: Когда куб переваливает через ребро, он вращается не относительно центра а относительно точки на ребре. Каждый 90 градусов точку вращения надо переставлять на следующее ребро. Первое что вам нужно - научится вращать объекты относительно точек лежащих вне центров этих объектов.

Comment: Учить нужно не Unity, а C#